# Repository Pattern vs DAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-access-layer

Are they the same thing? Just finished to watch [Rob Connery's Storefront tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-1-architectural-discussion-and-overview) and they seem to be similar techinques. I mean, when I implement a DAL object I have the GetStuff, Add/Delete etc methods and I always write the interface first so that I can switch db later.

Am I confusing things?

Answer (score 94):

You're definitely not the one who confuses things. :-)

I think the answer to the question depends on how much of a purist you want to be.

If you want a strict DDD point of view, that will take you down one path. If you look at the repository as a pattern that has helped us standardize the interface of the layer that separates between the services and the database it will take you down another.

The repository from my perspective is just a clearly specified layer of access to data.Or in other words a standardized way to implement your Data Access Layer. There are some differences between different repository implementations, but the concept is the same.

Some people will put more DDD constraints on the repository while others will use the repository as a convenient mediator between the database and the service layer. A repository like a DAL isolates the service layer from data access specifics.

One implementation issue that seems to make them different, is that a repository is often created with methods that take a specification. The repository will return data that satisfies that specification. Most traditional DALs that I have seen, will have a larger set of methods where the method will take any number of parameters. While this may sound like a small difference, it is a big issue when you enter the realms of Linq and Expressions.
Our default repository interface looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    T[] GetAll<T>();
    T[] GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    T GetSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    T GetSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> subSelectors);
    void Delete<T>(T entity);
    void Add<T>(T entity);
    int SaveChanges();
    DbTransaction BeginTransaction();
}
```

Is this a DAL or a repository? In this case I guess its both.

Kim

Comment: Late to the party here, but why T[], not List<T> (or similar)?

Comment: Perhaps IEnumerable<T> would be the best.

Comment: I think IQueryable<T> would be the best choice, because it allows you to chain methods and defer execution letting the database to do all the work.

Comment: I'd love to be able to chain methods together, but all our logic is wrapped up in sprocs. I am going to use this pattern, but without the benefit of the Expression chaining.

Comment: Since `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` - wouldn't the latter suffice? Consumers that need `IQueryable<T>` could use it, but others wouldn't have to?

Comment: @kenwarner I think returning IQueryable<T> leaks the abstraction. You should return domain objects from your repository.

Answer (score 48):

A repository is a pattern that can be applied in many different ways, while the data access layer has a very clear responsibility: the DAL must know how to connect to your data storage to perform CRUD operations.

A repository *can* be a DAL, but it can also sit in front of the DAL and act as a bridge between the business object layer and the data layer. Which implementation is used is going to vary from project to project.

Answer (score 23):

One large difference is that a DAO is a generic way to deal with persistence for any entity in your domain. A repository on the other hand only deals with aggregate roots.

Comment: The first thing to understand is that a repository as a pattern is part of the larger system known as Domain Driven Design. In DDD domain objects are grouped into aggregates, each with an aggregate root. E.g. PurchaseOrder is an aggregate root and OrderItems are children within the aggregate root. A repository only deals with aggregate roots. That is, a OrderItem for example is never loaded independently of it's aggreate root. So, you would never have an OrderItem repository in DDD. However, in a non-DDD system you could have an OrderItemDao since Dao isn't restricted to aggregate roots.

Comment: NG, Thanks!  I had started to see it that way, but this makes it clear.  I'll have to start reading all the DDD literature!

Comment: @bingle, great description of aggregate roots and how child objects are loaded by a repository. Where would a repository exist in a multi layered application? I could see it being in a data access layer library but since it loads child objects, should it exist in the logic layer library instead? My gut tells me data access layer but I wanted your opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for an answer to a similar question and agree with the two highest-ranked answers. Trying to clarify this for myself, I found that **if** Specifications, which go hand-in-hand with the Repository pattern, are implemented as first-class members of the domain model, then I can

- **reuse** Specification definitions with different parameters,
- **manipulate** existing Specification instances' parameters (e.g. to specialize),
- **combine** them,
- **perform business logic** on them without ever having to do any database access,
- and, of course, **unit-test** them independent of actual Repository implementations.

I may even go so far and state that *unless* the Repository pattern is used together with the Specification pattern, it's not really "Repository," but a DAL. A contrived example in pseudo-code:

```
specification100 = new AccountHasMoreOrdersThan(100)
specification200 = new AccountHasMoreOrdersThan(200)

assert that specification200.isSpecialCaseOf(specification100)

specificationAge = new AccountIsOlderThan('2000-01-01')

combinedSpec = new CompositeSpecification(
    SpecificationOperator.And, specification200, specificationAge)

for each account in Repository<Account>.GetAllSatisfying(combinedSpec)
    assert that account.Created < '2000-01-01'
    assert that account.Orders.Count > 200
```

See [Fowler's Specification Essay](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) for details (that's what I based the above on).

A DAL would have specialized methods like

```
IoCManager.InstanceFor<IAccountDAO>()
    .GetAccountsWithAtLeastOrdersAndCreatedBefore(200, '2000-01-01')
```

You can see how this can quickly become cumbersome, especially since you have to define each of the DAL/DAO interfaces with this approach *and* implement the DAL query method.

In .NET, LINQ queries *can* be one way to implement specifications, but combining Specification (expressions) may not be as smooth as with a home-grown solution. Some ideas for that are described in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316).

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that it is all about mapping, see: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html. So the output/input from the repository are domain objects, which on the DAL could be anything. For me that is an important addition/restriction, as you can add a repository implementation for a database/service/whatever with a different layout, and you have a clear place to concentrate on doing the mapping. If you were not to use that restriction and have the mapping elsewhere, then having different ways to represent data can impact the code in places it shouldn't be changing.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about interpretation and context. They can be very similar or indeed very different, but as long as the solution does the job, what is in a name!

Answer (score 1):

In the external world (i.e. client code) repository is same as DAL, except:

(1) it's insert/update/delete methods is restricted to have the data container object as the parameter.

(2) for read operation it may take simple specification like a DAL (for instance GetByPK) or advanced specification.

Internally it works with a Data Mapper Layer (for instance entity framework context etc) to perform the actual CRUD operation.

What Repository pattern doesn't mean:-

Also, I've seen people often get confused to have a separate Save method as the repository pattern sample implementation besides the Insert/Update/Delete methods which commits all the in-memory changes performed by insert/update/delete methods to database. We can have a Save method definitely in a repository, but that is not the responsibility of repository to isolate in-memory CUD (Create, Update, Delete) and persistence methods (that performs the actual write/change operation in database), but the responsibility of Unit Of Work pattern.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Repository is a pattern, this is a way to implement the things in standardized way to reuse the code as we can.

Answer (score 1):

Advantage of using repository pattern is to mock your data access layer, so that you can test your business layer code without calling DAL code. There are other big advantages but this seems to be very vital to me.

Comment: You can still mock a DAL, it need not be a repository per se.  The important point is that whatever data access strategy you use it should implement an interface.  This will allow you to use IoC containers as well as neatly test your business code without needing a data store.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand they can mean basically the same thing - but the naming varies based on context.

For example, you might have a Dal/Dao class that implements an IRepository interface.

Dal/Dao is a data layer term; the higher tiers of your application think in terms of Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

So in most of the (simple) cases DAO is an implementation of Repository?

As far as I understand,it seems that DAO deals precisely with db access (CRUD - No selects though?!)  while Repository allows you to abstract the whole data access,perhaps being a facade for multiple DAO (maybe different data sources).

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Actually, I'd reverse that and say that from a simplistic viewpoint, a Repository is a particular implementation style for a DAO, but yes, you're on the right path. (R from CRUD = Read, so that's your select.)

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that a "repository" is a specific class and a "DAL" is the entire layer consisting of the repositories, DTOs, utility classes, and anything else that is required.