# LINQ Expression to return Property value?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression

I'm trying to create a generic function to help me select thousands of records using LINQ to SQL from a local list.  SQL Server (2005 at least) limits queries to 2100 parameters and I'd like to select more records than that.

Here would be a good example usage:

```
var some_product_numbers = new int[] { 1,2,3 ... 9999 };

Products.SelectByParameterList(some_product_numbers, p => p.ProductNumber);
```

Here is my (non-working) implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectByParameterList<T, PropertyType>(Table<T> items, 

IEnumerable<PropertyType> parameterList, Expression<Func<T, PropertyType>> property) where T : class
{
    var groups = parameterList
        .Select((Parameter, index) =>
            new
            {
                GroupID = index / 2000, //2000 parameters per request
                Parameter
            }
        )
        .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
        .AsEnumerable();

    var results = groups
    .Select(g => new { Group = g, Parameters = g.Select(x => x.Parameter) } )
    .SelectMany(g => 
        /* THIS PART FAILS MISERABLY */
        items.Where(item => g.Parameters.Contains(property.Compile()(item)))
    );

    return results;
}
```

I have seen plenty of examples of building predicates using expressions.  In this case I only want to execute the delegate to return the value of the current ProductNumber.  Or rather, I want to translate this into the SQL query (it works fine in non-generic form).

I know that compiling the Expression just takes me back to square one (passing in the delegate as Func) but I'm unsure of how to pass a parameter to an "uncompiled" expression.

Thanks for your help!

**** EDIT:** Let me clarify further:

Here is a working example of what I want to generalize:

```
var local_refill_ids = Refills.Select(r => r.Id).Take(20).ToArray();

var groups = local_refill_ids
    .Select((Parameter, index) =>
        new
        {
            GroupID = index / 5, //5 parameters per request
            Parameter
        }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
    .AsEnumerable();

var results = groups
.Select(g => new { Group = g, Parameters = g.Select(x => x.Parameter) } )
.SelectMany(g => 
    Refills.Where(r => g.Parameters.Contains(r.Id))
)
.ToArray()
;
```

Results in this SQL code:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], ... [t0].[Version]
FROM [Refill] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)

... That query 4 more times (20 / 5 = 4)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to do this: Use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (Free, non-restrictive license)

Working version of code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectByParameterList<T, PropertyType>(this Table<T> items, IEnumerable<PropertyType> parameterList, Expression<Func<T, PropertyType>> propertySelector, int blockSize) where T : class
{
    var groups = parameterList
        .Select((Parameter, index) =>
            new
            {
                GroupID = index / blockSize, //# of parameters per request
                Parameter
            }
        )
        .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
        .AsEnumerable();

    var selector = LinqKit.Linq.Expr(propertySelector);

    var results = groups
    .Select(g => new { Group = g, Parameters = g.Select(x => x.Parameter) } )
    .SelectMany(g => 
        /* AsExpandable() extension method requires LinqKit DLL */
        items.AsExpandable().Where(item => g.Parameters.Contains(selector.Invoke(item)))
    );

    return results;
}
```

Example usage:

```
    Guid[] local_refill_ids = Refills.Select(r => r.Id).Take(20).ToArray();

    IEnumerable<Refill> results = Refills.SelectByParameterList(local_refill_ids, r => r.Id, 10); //runs 2 SQL queries with 10 parameters each
```

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I'd be interested in what the TSQL for that does, compared to my InRange reply...

Comment: SELECT [t0].[Id], ... [t0].[Version]
FROM [Refill] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9)

... That query 2times (20 / 10 = 2)

Comment: What is your suggestion for **blockSize** in order to optimize queries  using LinqToSql? Or, to put it differently, is it better to have less queries with bigger blocks, or more queries with smaller blocks?

Comment: You generally want as few blocks as possible.  The main issue is that SQL Server only allows 2100 parameters per query/command.  I'll usually use a blockSize of 2000.

Answer (score 46):

I've come up with a way to chunk the query into pieces - i.e. you give it 4000 values, so it might do 4 requests of 1000 each; with full Northwind example. Note that this might not work on Entity Framework, due to `Expression.Invoke` - but is fine on LINQ to SQL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication5 {
    /// SAMPLE USAGE
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // get some ids to play with...
            string[] ids;
            using(var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
                ids = ctx.Customers.Select(x => x.CustomerID)
                    .Take(100).ToArray();
            }

            // now do our fun select - using a deliberately small
            // batch size to prove it...
            using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
                ctx.Log = Console.Out;
                foreach(var cust in ctx.Customers
                        .InRange(x => x.CustomerID, 5, ids)) {
                    Console.WriteLine(cust.CompanyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// THIS IS THE INTERESTING BIT
    public static class QueryableChunked {
        public static IEnumerable<T> InRange<T, TValue>(
                this IQueryable<T> source,
                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector,
                int blockSize,
                IEnumerable<TValue> values) {
            MethodInfo method = null;
            foreach(MethodInfo tmp in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)) {
                if(tmp.Name == "Contains" && tmp.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && tmp.GetParameters().Length == 2) {
                    method = tmp.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TValue));
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(method==null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Unable to locate Contains");
            foreach(TValue[] block in values.GetBlocks(blockSize)) {
                var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "row");
                var member = Expression.Invoke(selector, row);
                var keys = Expression.Constant(block, typeof (TValue[]));
                var predicate = Expression.Call(method, keys, member);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
                      predicate, row);
                foreach(T record in source.Where(lambda)) {
                    yield return record;
                }
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetBlocks<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source, int blockSize) {
            List<T> list = new List<T>(blockSize);
            foreach(T item in source) {
                list.Add(item);
                if(list.Count == blockSize) {
                    yield return list.ToArray();
                    list.Clear();
                }
            }
            if(list.Count > 0) {
                yield return list.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This handles the case of `queryable.Where(o => values.Contains(o.propertyToTest))` by replacing it with `queryable.InRange(o => o.propertyToTest, blockSize, values)` (if I understand it correctly), but I'm looking at a similar overflow on the 2100 parameters limit, with e.g. `queryable.Where(o => !values.Contains(o.propertyToTest))`. I'm trying to modify InRange() to obtain a NotInRange() equivalent, and I'm not sure how to do the boolean negation. My thinking was at the `foreach (T record in source.Where(lambda))` line?

Comment: Actually, after much hunting, I think I've found what's needed, appropriately from an answer you'd given a month previously to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool#457328, ref "This also works well to negate a single operation:"

Comment: @Marc - How would this be handled in VB? `yield return` obviously doesn't exist for us.

Comment: What is the reason for making the batch size configurable? Wouldn't I always want this to be like 2090? So I'm just under the 2100 limit with a bit of play?

Comment: The Invoke isn't necessary. You can re-use the selector lambda and parameter, although I admit it's a bit dirty. Avoiding the invoke will also make it usable on other ORMs I think. (I made it working on LLBLGen Pro using: https://gist.github.com/FransBouma/5e7031fe557df4b5b688

Answer (score 3):

LINQ-to-SQL still works via standard SQL parameters, so writing a fancy expression isn't going to help. There are 3 common options here:

- pack the ids into (for example) csv/tsv; pass down as a `varchar(max)` and use a udf to split it (at the server) into a table variable; join to the table variable
- use a table-valued-parameter in SQL Server 2008
- have a table on the server that you could push the ids into (perhaps via SqlBulkCopy) (perhaps with a "session guid" or similar); join to this table

The first is the simplest; getting a "split csv udf" is trivial (just search for it). Drag the udf onto the data-context and consume from there.

Comment: This isn't necessary. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `IQuerable` to the `Contains` function instead of list or array. please see the below example

```
var df_handsets = db.DataFeed_Handsets.Where(m => m.LaunchDate != null).
                  Select(m => m.Name);
var Make = (from m in db.MobilePhones
    where (m.IsDeleted != true || m.IsDeleted == null)
        && df_handsets.Contains(m.Name)
    orderby m.Make
    select new { Value = m.Make, Text = m.Make }).Distinct();
```

when you pass list or array it is passed in form of parameters and its exceed the counts when the list items count is greater than 2100.

Comment: You are assuming the collection to match against is coming from the database itself.  This is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own QueryProvider

```
public class QueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    // Translates LINQ query to SQL.
    private readonly Func<IQueryable, DbCommand> _translator;

    // Executes the translated SQL and retrieves results.
    private readonly Func<Type, string, object[], IEnumerable> _executor;

    public QueryProvider(
        Func<IQueryable, DbCommand> translator,
        Func<Type, string, object[], IEnumerable> executor)
    {

        this._translator = translator;
        this._executor = executor;
    }

    #region IQueryProvider Members

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new Queryable<TElement>(this, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        bool isCollection = typeof(TResult).IsGenericType &&
            typeof(TResult).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
        var itemType = isCollection
            // TResult is an IEnumerable`1 collection.
            ? typeof(TResult).GetGenericArguments().Single()
            // TResult is not an IEnumerable`1 collection, but a single item.
            : typeof(TResult);
        var queryable = Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(Queryable<>).MakeGenericType(itemType), this, expression) as IQueryable;

        IEnumerable queryResult;

        // Translates LINQ query to SQL.
        using (var command = this._translator(queryable))
        {
            var parameters = command.Parameters.OfType<DbParameter>()
                .Select(parameter => parameter)
                .ToList();

            var query = command.CommandText;
            var newParameters = GetNewParameterList(ref query, parameters);

            queryResult = _executor(itemType,query,newParameters);
        }

        return isCollection
            ? (TResult)queryResult // Returns an IEnumerable`1 collection.
            : queryResult.OfType<TResult>()
                         .SingleOrDefault(); // Returns a single item.
    }       

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

     private static object[] GetNewParameterList(ref string query, List<DbParameter> parameters)
    {
        var newParameters = new List<DbParameter>(parameters);

        foreach (var dbParameter in parameters.Where(p => p.DbType == System.Data.DbType.Int32))
        {
            var name = dbParameter.ParameterName;
            var value = dbParameter.Value != null ? dbParameter.Value.ToString() : "NULL";
            var pattern = String.Format("{0}[^0-9]", dbParameter.ParameterName);
            query = Regex.Replace(query, pattern, match => value + match.Value.Replace(name, ""));
            newParameters.Remove(dbParameter);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < newParameters.Count; i++)
        {
            var parameter = newParameters[i];
            var oldName = parameter.ParameterName;
            var pattern = String.Format("{0}[^0-9]", oldName);
            var newName = "@p" + i;
            query = Regex.Replace(query, pattern, match => newName + match.Value.Replace(oldName, ""));
        }      

        return newParameters.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
    }
}


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dc=new DataContext())
        {
            var provider = new QueryProvider(dc.GetCommand, dc.ExecuteQuery);

            var serviceIds = Enumerable.Range(1, 2200).ToArray();

            var tasks = new Queryable<Task>(provider, dc.Tasks).Where(x => serviceIds.Contains(x.ServiceId) && x.CreatorId==37 && x.Creator.Name=="12312").ToArray();

        }

    }
```