# Hitting the 2100 parameter limit (SQL Server) when using Contains()

Tags: sql-server, linq, parameters, limit

```
from f in CUSTOMERS
where depts.Contains(f.DEPT_ID)
select f.NAME
```

`depts` is a list (`IEnumerable<int>`) of department ids

This query works fine until you pass a large list (say around 3000 dept ids) .. then I get this error:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.

I changed my query to:

```
var dept_ids = string.Join(" ", depts.ToStringArray());
from f in CUSTOMERS
where dept_ids.IndexOf(Convert.ToString(f.DEPT_id)) != -1
select f.NAME
```

using `IndexOf()` fixed the error but made the query slow. Is there any other way to solve this? thanks so much.

Comment: How about [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771) (which batches it into manageable pieces). The other (non-LINQ) options involve CSV and a "split" UDF, and table-valued-parameters (in SQL2008).

Comment: Mark, can you please explain what is best alternative to `contain` if I have various parameters count from 1 to 2000? I know that this create bunch of plans in db, but it seems that usage of `like <input parameter> '%<search field>%'` will take even more db resource time. What should I use?

Comment: The 2100 parameter limit problem does not exist in Entity Framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898564/entity-framework-hitting-2100-parameter-limit

Comment: did you tried any solution? not marked none

Comment: What about when search for `DEPT_id` when equals 1, will find any id has 1 in any digit! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17):

My solution (`Guids` is a list of ids you would like to filter by):

```
List<MyTestEntity> result = new List<MyTestEntity>();
for(int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)Guids.Count / 2000); i++)
{
    var nextGuids = Guids.Skip(i * 2000).Take(2000);
    result.AddRange(db.Tests.Where(x => nextGuids.Contains(x.Id)));
}
this.DataContext = result;
```

Comment: Rather than using Ceiling (and multiplying in Skip) and incrementing by 1, just use Count for the condition and increment by 2000. Also make it a constant to make it configurable.

Answer (score 6):

Why not write the query in sql and attach your entity?

It's been awhile since I worked in Linq, but here goes:

```
IQuery q = Session.CreateQuery(@"
         select * 
         from customerTable f
         where f.DEPT_id in (" + string.Join(",", depts.ToStringArray()) + ")");
q.AttachEntity(CUSTOMER);
```

Of course, you will need to protect against injection, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: thanks joel. let me try it and i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Caveat: that is OK with integers, but with strings: watch out for SQL injection.

Comment: Presumably you want a comma in there somewhere, Joel?

Comment: Yes, injection is always a concern when writing dynamic sql, but with integers you're safer. 
Comma added. ;)

Comment: hi joel, thanks again for taking time to answer my question. :-)

Comment: @George, If you read to the end (or the comments), you'll notice I warned against the injection risk.

Comment: Ugly, but somehow a nice workaround :)
Why is there a parameter number limit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the statement gets large enough you will still hit a limit. I think it was 65k characters at one point?

Comment: This might generate terrible performance with non demo queries that contain joins and filters (and sometimes a complex query error)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check out the [LINQKit project](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) since within there somewhere is a technique for batching up such statements to solve this issue. I believe the idea is to use the PredicateBuilder to break the local collection into smaller chuncks but I haven't reviewed the solution in detail because I've instead been looking for a more natural way to handle this.

Unfortunately it appears from [Microsoft's response to my suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475984) to fix this behavior that there are no plans set to have this addressed for .NET Framework 4.0 or even subsequent service packs.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475984

UPDATE:

I've opened up some discussion regarding whether this was going to be fixed for [LINQ to SQL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosqlprerelease/thread/c354f12a-903c-4456-84b6-c04d5bb4b8eb) or the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/b5e89594-f638-46de-9ffd-4b07ed28ec68?prof=required) on the MSDN forums. Please see these posts for more information regarding these topics and to see the temporary workaround that I've come up with using XML and a SQL UDF.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and I got two ways to fix it.

1. [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345609.aspx) method
2. join on IDs

To get values that are NOT in list, I used [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348938.aspx) method OR left join.

**Update**

EntityFramework 6.2 runs the following query successfully:

```
var employeeIDs = Enumerable.Range(3, 5000);
var orders =
    from order in Orders
    where employeeIDs.Contains((int)order.EmployeeID)
    select order;
```

Comment: Could you give an example how to do it?

Comment: The limit is a server limit. What was the resulting query that didn't cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your post was from a while ago, but perhaps someone will benefit from this.  Entity Framework does a lot of query caching, every time you send in a different parameter count, that gets added to the cache.  Using a "Contains" call will cause SQL to generate a clause like "WHERE x IN (@p1, @p2.... @pn)", and bloat the EF cache.

Recently I looked for a new way to handle this, and I found that you can create an entire table of data as a parameter.  Here's how to do it:

First, you'll need to create a custom table type, so run this in SQL Server (in my case I called the custom type "TableId"):

```
        CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableId] AS TABLE(
            Id[int] PRIMARY KEY
        )
```

Then, in C#, you can create a DataTable and load it into a structured parameter that matches the type.  You can add as many data rows as you want:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
```

This is an arbitrary list of IDs to search on.  You can make the list as large as you want:

```
        dt.Rows.Add(24262);
        dt.Rows.Add(24267);
        dt.Rows.Add(24264);
```

Create an SqlParameter using the custom table type and your data table:

```
        SqlParameter tableParameter = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Structured);
        tableParameter.TypeName = "dbo.TableId";
        tableParameter.Value = dt;
```

Then you can call a bit of SQL from your context that joins your existing table to the values from your table parameter.  This will give you all records that match your ID list:

```
        var items = context.Dailies.FromSqlRaw<Dailies>("SELECT * FROM dbo.Dailies d INNER JOIN @id id ON d.Daily_ID = id.id", tableParameter).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always partition your list of depts into smaller sets before you pass them as parameters to the IN statement generated by Linq.  See here:

[Divide a large IEnumerable into smaller IEnumerable of a fix amount of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172390/divide-a-large-ienumerable-into-smaller-ienumerable-of-a-fix-amount-of-item)

Comment: These solutions work for simple logic and cannot be expanded into an approach. The general case is that the list is a single parameter for a query that usually has other filters and must return a page.