# too many parameters were provided in this rpc request. the maximum is 2100 when less than 2100 parameters exist in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm receiving the TDS RPC error that the rpc request exceeds 2100 parameters on a stored procedure call.  However, i'm only showing 2042 parameters in the query when I run the SQL Profiler and I'm able to run the stored procedure with the query from the profiler without issue.  However, the web application is still throwing that error.

Is the actual limit less than 2100 or are there different variables that count towards the parameter limit?

Comment: Holy smokes, that's a lot of parameters!

Comment: yeah it's due to a linq query with contains() and it parses out each of the objects.  I don't have access to modify the code so I was hoping there was some other method to clear this up.

Comment: Couple of linq solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028547/too-many-parameters-were-provided-in-this-rpc-request-the-maximum-is-2100