# ADO.NET Batch Insert with over 2000 parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

I'm using Enterprise library, but the idea is the same. I have a  SqlStringCommand and the sql

is constructed using StringBuilder in the forms of

```
"insert into table (column1, column2, column3) values (@param1-X, @param2-X, @parm3-X)"+" "
```

where "X" represents a "for loop" about 700 rows

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<700; i++)
{
   sb.Append("insert into table (column1, column2, column3) values (@param1-"+i+", @param2-"+i, +",@parm3-"+i+") " );
}
```

followed by constructing a command object injecting all the parameters w/ values into it.

Essentially, 700 rows with 3 parameters, I ended up with 2100 parameters for this "one sql" Statement.

It ran fine for about a few days and suddenly I got this error

```
===============================================================

A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNon
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have 2100 parameters then you need to rethink your process.

Comment: with that much data have you hit your db limit? are you on full sql?

Comment: Hello Durlai and seanxe:

I'm importing a text file with 800 some records, do some processing to get rid of some items, constructed a IList object and import them into my db in the middle of a transaction.

I can loop through the records and do insert one at a time, no problem. In fact, I did that, it works great,  but because the list can grow overtime, i would like to execute the statements in one round trip instead of 700 round trips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but check this out: [Hitting the 2100 parameter limit (SQL Server) when using Contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains)

Comment: That's it durilai. I just tested! if I remove one record and such the number of parameters are 3*699=2097, it's OK! Once it hits 2100, boom!

Comment: In case others want to know. Here are the limits on MSDN. Never thought I would care ever, but now I do. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). It will probably offer a better solution to your problem than  your current approach.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I looked into it, however, the operation is in the middle of a transaction, SQLBUlkCopy doesn't not offer a parameter for transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can resolve this one of many ways

1. Batch inserts for every 100 records
2. Do each insert as it's own command with a transaction wrapped around all inserts.
3. Use SQL Bulk Copy
4. Use SSIS for this: ETL tasks are best done using ETL tools. Since you are using SQL Server, you can easily load up data files into SQL Server using SSIS. You can build an SSIS package and execute it from within your C# code.

Comment: Thanks Raj. #2 is sort of what I'm doing now, #3, I can't do it because it's in the mdidle of a transaction and SQLBulkCopy Class doesn not offer a parameter for transaction. #4 is not an option as it's a import tool build into our asp.net application. However, I think #1 might be the way to go. I'll give that a try.