# Selecting id from database where not in large collection, Too many parameters provided

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, multiple-databases

I am working on a application that has two databases.

I have an object, let's call it `permit`, that has a list of id's referencing to id's from a table, lets call that `tasks`, in the other database.

I am trying to run the following query:

```
var listOfUsedIds = select taskid from Permit_Task;
Select * from task where id not in (listOfUsedIds)
```

When I run this code I get the error:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect.
>   Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum
>   is 2100.

I can't run a sub select or any thing because NHibernate won't let me do that over two databases.

Can anyone help me how to work around this problem?

Comment: you would check this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains

Comment: The message is clear: `**too many parameters** were provided`. Solution: use **less** parameters....

Comment: One option is to insert the ids into a temporary table first. Temporary tables are often stored in memory and quite efficient.

Comment: This should not be closed as duplicate of a query that hits the limit using contains -- with contains the client can fire multiple queries and trivially union the results; with **not in** the client side operations becomes more complex

Comment: @Davide Piras the OP states `not in` which excludes batches i think

Comment: You can create a link server and fetch the table of second database from first database. It's possible in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.CreateSQLQuery("CREATE TEMP TABLE usedIds (id INT)").ExecuteUpdate();

    for (int index = 0; index < ids.Length; index++)
    {
        // TODO: batch this
        session.CreateSQLQuery("INSERT INTO usedIds VALUES (:p" + index + ")")
            .SetParameter("p" + index, id)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
    }

    session.CreateSQLQuery("CREATE INDEX usedIds_idx ON usedIds (id)").ExecuteUpdate();


    Batch batch;
    while((batch.List = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT id FROM tasks t WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usedIds u WHERE u.id = t.id) LIMIT 10 OFFSET " + batch.Number).List<int>()).Count > 0)

    {
        var tasks = session.QueryOver<Task>()
            .Where(t => t.Id.IsIn(batch))
            .List();
        // Do something with the tasks
    }
    tx.Commit();
}
```

or

```
public TaskMap()
{

    Map(x => x.IsUsedCount).Formula("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usedIds u WHERE u.Id = Id)").LazyLoad();
}

var tasks = session.QueryOver<Task>()
    .Where(t => t.IsUsedCount == 0)
    .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just break the `listOfUsedIds` into smaller blocks (say, 200 ids each), run the query for each block, and `.Concat()` the results.