# Avoiding the 2100 rpc limit with LINQ Select and Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, rpc

I have the following query.  In it I'm doing a Take(2100) to avoid the 2100 rpc limit imposed.

```
 var query =
     from result in staging_sparc_sophis_trade.AsQueryable()
     where deals.Take(2100).Contains(result.TRADE_ID)
     select new traded_product()
     {                   
        Deal = result.TRADE_ID,
        CostCentre = result.FTP_COSTCTR,
       InvolvedPartyId = R_GEN_002(result.hsbc_source_system_instance, "", result.CNPTY_ACRONYM
     };
```

What I want to know is, is there a way I can remove the Take(2100) part and replace it with a lambda statement in the Deal line to check if the deal is in the list (deals) I'm searching for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hitting the 2100 parameter limit (sql-server) when using Contains()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains)

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg yes, I was looking at doing a loop and joining all the results at the end.  but I wasn't sure if there was an elegant Lambda solution.  Think not.

Comment: We used a parameterized datatable for mssql. It may not be the perfect solution, but should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found 2 ways round the problem.
Solution 1.  If I run the query on the SqlServer physical machine directly, the problem does not occur.

Do the filtering in the next part:
Remove the "Where clause"

```
var query =
 from result in staging_sparc_sophis_trade.AsQueryable()
 --where deals.Take(2100).Contains(result.TRADE_ID)
 select new traded_product()
 {                   
    Deal = result.TRADE_ID,
    CostCentre = result.FTP_COSTCTR,
   InvolvedPartyId = R_GEN_002(result.hsbc_source_system_instance, "", result.CNPTY_ACRONYM
 };
```

Add the filtering part in this part of your code.  It runs a bit slower, but still does the trick.  I think it runs slower because I'm searching the full list in every single itteration.

```
foreach (var result in query)
{
if (!deals.contains(result.TRADE_ID))
{
--Actions
}
}
```