# LINQ with IN clause with exact matches

Tags: c#, string, linq, contains, in-clause

I'm using LINQ to query my database and my records have a status (Active, Inactive, Hold, Pending, etc...).  When I do a contains with the inactive status it also returns active since it does contain that value.

My UI allows the user to check off which statuses they want to return which I pass to my back-end as an array.  I know that doing an IN clause in LINQ goes like this "where statuses.contains(t.Status)".  My problem is that if I pass in Inactive it will match active because it does contain the word.  In T-SQL if I had WHERE status IN ('Inactive') it would only return records that are inactive. Has anyone one done something that behaves like a T-SQL IN clause?

Comment: What's `statuses`? A List of enums?

Comment: You need to post the code as well. It's not very clear what you are doing at the moment. What type is status?

Comment: `Contains` is a method on `IEnumerable` and also on `String` so it is not clear  what you are using when you mention `where statuses.contains(t.Status)`

Comment: It is likely that @Zoey has created a string with comma separated values in it `"a,b,c"`. When she should be using instead an **array** of strings `["a", "b", "c"]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991481/in-clause-in-linq-expression is likely worth a read.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the problem is that "Inactive" contains "active". That means you're checking to see if a string contains a string, not checking whether a set of strings contains a string. But either way, this is is impossible to answer without some code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to demo my app.  statuses is a comma delimited string of statuses: "Active, Inactive".  Maybe that's why it's doing a CHARINDEX instead of IN (I ran profiler to see what the query was doing).  I'm deserializing JSON from Angular so my filters are a Dictionary<string, string> of which one is a list of statuses.  Maybe if I switch this to a List<string> it will do an in clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm embarrassed to say my problem was because it was using a string with comma separated values rather than a string array.  As soon as I switch to a string array my query used an IN clause rather than CHARINDEX.

My apologies for not being more specific in my question. @mjwills I noticed you had the answer after I refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell exactly what you want without code here.

but this is what im guessing...

You are doing a `.Contains("active")` and that's returning rows that are also status of `Inactive`?

If that's the case can't you do something like this?

```
var active = rows.Where(r => { r.status == "active" });
```

If this is not correct please can you post some code to help us out a little.

Thanks.