# How to overcome SQL Server limitation for "IN" query parameters count?

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a T-SQL query with something like:

```
WHERE 
    tbl.field IN (%a lot of variants%)
```

But I can't because of limitation of 2100 items for parameters count in SQL Server.

How can I find the way around this problem?

Comment: Use a table type parameter/variable instead. `IN`, however, can support way more than 2,100 inline values; it's not till you get many thousands of values that you start to get performance issues either.

Comment: Your question doesn't stipulate, but I suspect you are experiencing limitation when using LINQ. Can you confirm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains

Comment: This [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=958e9cbd04ae024222d9057af99c1a6b), for example, uses an `IN` with **10,000** inline values and doesn't error.

Comment: Thank you all for answers! But apparently my proplem was caused by HQL "IN" clause. So i rewrote it and problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and pass the list not as individual parameters, but as a single NVARCHAR(MAX) parameter that's parsed on the server.  EG

```
select * 
from large 
where id in (select cast(value as int) from openjson(@values))
```

Where @values is a parameter of type NVARCHAR(MAX) containint a JSON Array of scalars.  Like

```
var values = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]";
```

And as a bonus it performs much better too.

Comment: In my tests openjson is about 10% slower than the orthodox in-clause.

Comment: But it scales better for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to you a subquery!

```
SELECT VAR1, VAR2    
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
  (SELECT.. FROM.. ETC)
```