# maximum number of parameters in sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2005-express

I do experiment with LINQ since some time.
Typical method to enumerate through a collection and change some of its properties in my code would look like:

```
ATDataContext dc = new ATDataContext(Settings.connection_string);

int[] col = ListViewClass.getListViewSelectedPositionTags(listView);

try
{
    foreach (var item in col)
    {
        var ctx = (from r in dc.MailingLists
                   where r.ID == item
                   select r).Single();

        ctx.Excluded = 'Y';
        ctx.ExcludedComments = reason;
    }

    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Later on I have got an advice to do this by... seems like much smarter way:

```
var ctx = from r in dc.MailingLists
    where col.Contains(r.ID)
    select r;

foreach (var item in ctx)
{
    item.Excluded = 'Y';
    item.ExcludedComments = reason;
}

dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Iit makes sense on so many levels and I love this solution. It’s smart and faster than the first one.

I have used this solution in a production environment for some time.

What was my surprise after few weeks when searching an application log files and see this:

***"The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RCP request. The maximum is 2100."***

The LINQ to SQL converts `where col.Contains(r.ID)` to `IN`clause looking something like:
WHERE ID IN (@p1, @p1, @p2 … )

The `col` collection reached (in my case) more than 2100 elements and the query failed to perform. I have done some research on the problem and what I ended up is:

***“… Maximum number of parameters in the sql query is 2100. There is more limitations, like the fact that the whole query string cannot be longer than 8044 characters.”***

I have loved the second solution so much. I am so disappointed with these hard-coded limitations of the SQL Server.

Did I miss something?
Is there anything I can do to be able to use the `where col.Contains(r.ID)` version?

Comment: Apologies. I didn't manage to format code samples. If someone could help I would appreciate very much...

Comment: formatted; you can use the "code" and "quote" buttons to do this in the editor.

Comment: `I have loved the second solution so much`: "It is better to have loved and lost, than never to have loved at all"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The limits [are hard-coded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

- Parameters per stored procedure 2,100
- Parameters per user-defined function 2,100

I wrote some code before that split the `Contains` query into batches and combined the results... [see here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771).

Comment: turns out the error message/documentation is wrong.  They must have a check that goes `>= 2100` rather than > 2100 because the actual limit is 2099 just observed this with trying to send 4 parameter batch, which gives an even size of 525

Comment: @JonnyLeeds interesting; I wonder if it does something like always include space for a return value (even if not used), which is implemented kinda as a parameter

Comment: yeah possibly.  The documentation there only specifically mentions functions and stored procedures, whereas I was just running a big set of inserts, however the exceptions from running `command.Execute[Blah]` (in c#) also mention 2100

Comment: When C# calls SQL Server without a stored proc, it uses `sp_executesql`. This means you're using one parameter for the SQL statement itself.

Comment: @Jonathan if that wer the case, it would be using 2 - one for the SQL and one for the params definition parameter; I didn't think it actually issued it that way, though, at the TDS level - but I could be wrong, it has been a while since I dabbled with raw TDS

Comment: I can't say you're wrong, all I know for certain is that my C# code can't use the full 2100 parameters.