# Pyodbc - SQL Truncating Parameters

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I am passing about 80k parameters but while executing the query, it seems like `pyodbc` or `SQL` is truncating the total number of parameters. It works when I pass around 2k parameters but fails anything above 2k. Below is my queries and I will highly appreciate your help.

```
contact_lst = df_attempt_filtered['Contact ID'].unique()
len(contact_lst) ### Prints: 80871

query_contact = """
SELECT DISTINCT
    con.CONTACT_ID,
    con.JOB_ROLE,
    con.JOB_FUNCTION,
    con.MAIN_PHONE_NUM,
    con.WORK_PHONE_NUM,
    con.MOBILE_PHONE_NUM,
    acc.EMPLOYEE_COUNT AS "EmpSize"
FROM
    V_S_CONTACT_w_MOBILE_NUM AS con
LEFT JOIN 
    V_S_ACCOUNT_ALL_w_others as acc
        ON CON.ACCOUNT_ID = ACC.ACCT_ID
WHERE
    con.CONTACT_ID IN ({})""".format(", ".join(["?"]*len(contact_lst)))

df_contacts = pd.read_sql(query_contact, con=conn, params=contact_lst)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 15335 parameter markers, but 80871 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
>    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: *"I am passing about 80k parameters"* There's your problem. Use a temporary table/table variable. An `IN` with 80,000 values it in will [probably kill your instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maximum number of parameters in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845931/maximum-number-of-parameters-in-sql-query)

Comment: use a table valued parameter to supply 80k values - pyodbc example https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/969ea2c42712036d473fab5d4db715452580c6d3/tests3/sqlservertests.py#L1647

Comment: The fact that you need 80,000 parameters seems like an XY problem unto itself, if I'm honest.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround:
You can create a XML or JSON string in python and then pass it as a single parameter.
Then you will shred this JSON/XML in the query.

Comment: Thanks, Piotr. Any sample code to work off it?

Comment: There is a nice example for VB, it will be easy to translate to python https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555266