# How to add more than 10000 parameters to a single sql command

Tags: c#

I want to add  more than 10000 parameters to a single sql command. How it possible?
As far i know 2100 parameters a single sql command.

Comment: You do not want to add more than 10000 parameters to an SQL command.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx and search parameters keyword :)

Comment: We passed WTF City riding straight to Helltown. No, really, why? Maybe there is a better solution than using 10k parameters?

Comment: Hehe, this has been asked before.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771

Comment: The fact that this question has two upvotes makes me think that I am doing question voting wrong.

Comment: I have to vote this question up JUST because I needed a laugh tongight

Comment: @AakashM: The fact that the OP's solution is to his problem is a bad idea does not mean his question is a bad question.  If nothing else, it is somewhat educational since answering it involves a discussion of useful stuff like `SqlBulkCopy`.

Answer (score 13):

I think you step back to the "why" rather than jumping right to the "how". It sounds like maybe you are doing some huge insert/update, in which case a more appropriate solution would be table-valued-parameters.

Other options include:

- passing in xml and using SQL server to parse the xml (it is quite good at this)
- loading data *first* with something like `SqlBulkCopy` into a staging table, then executing a command (raw TSQL or a SPROC) to push the data from the staging table into the transactional tables
- if it is just a list of ids, write a "split" function (udf) at the server and pass in a `[n]varchar(max)`
- batch the operations into a number of more sane commands

You really don't want to do something with 10k parameters on one command; that way madness lies.

Comment: The limit is 2100, because at 2101, the Shub-SQLurath will be summoned, and darkness will engulf the earth, as foretold in the Databasenomicron.

Comment: I am generating insert query and 10000 parameter from 10000 objects.I want to execute this query by a single command.Have any way to execute this query by a single round trip to Database?

Comment: @Engr - no, that simply isn't the way to do it. Break it into multiple commands, or use any of the tricks I mentioned above. For inserts, table-valued parameters is pretty much **designed** for this scenario - why not use them?

Comment: @Engr Why not just insert each object one after the other in a transaction instead? Makes things simple that way

Comment: @w69rdy round trips start to hurt you at that volume

Comment: @w69rdy plus: anyone opens a transaction spanning 10k round-trips on one of my systems is going to get shot

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` *without* a staging table is also a reasonable way to perform a bulk insert, if the data doesn't need to be modified on the server before being inserted.

Comment: @Brian that depends a bit on your transaction log configuration. Bulk inserts can be non-logged

Answer (score 3):

You can't. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

Your only option is to generate a SQL string containing all those parameter values.

Incidentally, SQL CE does not have this limitation.