# List<Int32> Join with a Table in LINQ-SQL Recommendation Request

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a list of account ids to retrieve from a different context and need to be able to do this:

```
List<Account> MyMethod(List<int> Accounts)
{
    List<Account> accounts = dc.Accounts.Join(Accounts,
                                              x => x.AccountID,
                                              y => y,
                                              (x, y) => x).ToList<Account>();
    return accounts;
}
```

It's obviously not a working query but what is the best way to handle this kind of request?

:::::UPDATE::::

Basically I came up with this solution but it's not complete:

```
accounts = (from a in dc.Accounts
                        where Accounts.Contains(a.AccountID)
                        select a).ToList<Account>();
```

However, how do you write it as a lambda-expression? I can't get Accounts.Contains(x=>x.AccountID) to work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Obviously?  I understand the problem but I wouldn't say it is "obvious."  One might argue that it is perfectly good LINQ code upon inspection.  ;)

Comment: What obvious reasons? This is exactly what this linq query will get translated to: `dc.Accounts.Where(x => Accounts.Contains(x.AccoundID)).Tolist();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
List<Account> MyMethod(List<int> accounts)
{
    return dc.Accounts.Where(x => accounts.Contains(x.AccountID))
                      .ToList();
}
```

EDIT: Note that for more information about how query expressions are translated into non-query form, see [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) in my Edulinq blog series.

Comment: it's complaining about time limit so i can't mark it as answered straight away otherwise i would have but thank you again anyway.

Comment: This works with a caveat ... if the list is too long this will blow up ... I think its blows up at around 100. for the record sql server supports about 2000 params

Comment: @Sam: Any idea why the LINQ to SQL limit is so much lower than SQL server itself?

Comment: @Jon I "think" it this is the reason http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html you are stuck passing in nvarchar(4000) in Sql Server 7 and 2000 ... so they went for the wider support. Seems a bit of an odd decision to me. (see the sp_executesql section)

Comment: Note actually max param capacity link is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution: [LINQ Expression to return Property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771)