# To many nested statements

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I have a c# code as follows

```
var deptSalesQuery = 
    from d in db.DashboardFigures
    join s in outlets.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)) on d.OutletNo equals s
    where (d.TypeOfinformation == "SALES")
    group d by new
    {
        d.Number
    } into newGroupedresult
    select new DeptSales()
    { 
        Dn =   (int)newGroupedresult.Key.Number,
        Qs = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_4),
        Se = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_2),
        Si = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_3) 
           + (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_2)
    };
```

When I pass in Outlets = "1,2,3,4,....all the way upto 110", the software crashes telling me that there are too many nested statements.

Is there any way that I can remove the JOIN and add something onto the WHERE clause to help the situation?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `Contains` method to check if `outlets.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x))` contains the `d.OutletNo`

Comment: Something like `where outlets.Split(',').Select(int.Parsex).Contains(d.OutletNo) && d.TypeOfinformation == "SALES"`

Comment: In EF there doesn't seem to be a maximum limit for `Contains` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898564/entity-framework-hitting-2100-parameter-limit). Are you using EF or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: I'd start by doing the splitting and parsing outside of the main Linq query.

Comment: @xanatos , Im using EF. Also I tried the statement in the WHERE clause, but the error is that LINQ to Entities does not recognise Split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written by juharr, before the query do:

```
int[] splitted = outlets.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
```

and in the query:

```
where splitted.Contains(d.OutletNo) && d.TypeOfinformation == "SALES"
```

Comment: `select` return `IEnumerable` so first string raise error

Comment: @juharr Thanks a lot, this seems to be working now. more testing will tell. However, thank you both.