# The incoming request has too many parameters, The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm working in Webform application and using Entity Framwork with a `.edmx` file.
My `.edmx` file contains almost 350 tables, so I divided it to many diagrams.
Now I can't add new table to edmx file as when I try to add new table I have this error:

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by use fewer paramaters. I just added tables to my edmx file.

Comment: Consider splitting table definitions and chunk large queries to smaller pieces - like this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898564/entity-framework-hitting-2100-parameter-limit.