# Linq-To-SQL Marc Gravell's InRange Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, lambda, extension-methods

I'm tring to use the `InRange` extension Marc Gravell wrote here:

[LINQ Expression to return Property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771)

This is my code so far:

```
// Fetch list of visit Ids and distinct Ips that fall into the date range
var q = (from c in db.tblTrackerVisits where c.Date >= MinDate select new { c.ID, c.IPID });
List<int> VisitIDs = q.Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
List<int> DistinctIPs = q.Select(c => c.IPID).Distinct().ToList();

// List of all campaigns that have visitors
var Campaigns = db.tblTrackerVariables
    .Where(c => 
        c.TypeID == Settings.CampaignTrackerVariableTypeID
        //&& db.tblTrackerVisitVariables.Any(d=>VisitIDs.Contains(d.VisitID) && d.VariableID == c.ID)
        && db.tblTrackerVisitVariables.InRange(x => x.VisitID, 1500, VisitIDs)
    )
    .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Name }).OrderBy(c=>c.Name);
```

However this throws:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<tblTrackerVisitVariable>' to 'bool'
```

I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, can anyone give me some pointers?  The commented out && above it:

```
//&& db.tblTrackerVisitVariables.Any(d=>VisitIDs.Contains(d.VisitID) && d.VariableID == c.ID)
```

Is the old working code (but it throws the too many params error so I have to resort to this extension method).

Comment: wait.... what am I being blamed for now? ;p

Answer (score 3):

Mark's extension method returns an `IEnumerable`, not a `bool`, and therefore cannot be included in a logical expression. I you want to check if the result is non-empty try the `Any` method:

```
db.tblTrackerVisitVariables.InRange(x => x.VisitID, 1500, VisitIDs).Any()
```

Comment: Ah crap, so if I'm getting the `The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.` what are my options?  Do I have to redesign all my queries?

Comment: Do you want to check if the result of InRange has any elements?

Comment: Please use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`

Comment: @Oliver: Added your suggestion.

Comment: @TomGullen Yes, you will.  This goes down to the .Net Sql client level and Sql server (I believe).  Typically when I hit this, I break the parameters into chunks and repeat the query for each set of 2000 parameters, then union the result together on the client.

Comment: @Oliver, I use any but if after the query I do `List<int> VariableIDs = Campaigns.Select(c => c.ID).ToList();` it throws the error at runtime `Method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[tblTrackerVisitVariable] InRange[tblTrackerVisitVariable,Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[tblTrackerVisitVariable], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[tblTrackerVisitVariable,System.Int32]], Int32, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' has no supported translation to SQL.`