# How to send large filterlist in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a pretty big table where I want to get certain rows by Id. To save data I need to send a list of Ids, which can be up to a few thousands. I've tried the way to send the ids by commaseperated string to a stored procedure, but to convert the string back to a selectable list took a few minutes. 
Now I've tried with Contains on a view, but I always get an error, that I used too many parameters.

Is there a best practice way to solve my problem? Thanks in advance - hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Show your code with `Contains`

Comment: Not sure about in linq but with C# and direct sql, you might want to look into TVPs (table value parameters).  It's a way to send an in memory table to a sproc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With direct C# and SQL, you can use table value parameters - it's a way to pass an in memory table to a sproc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

I don't believe Linq supports it.  But, I found this article concerning using TVPs via Linq with a workaround (haven't tried it):

http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

From [Hitting the 2100 parameter limit (SQL Server) when using Contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains)

> How about [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567963/linq-expression-to-return-property-value/568771#568771) (which batches it into manageable pieces). The
>   other (non-LINQ) options involve CSV and a "split" UDF, and
>   table-valued-parameters (in SQL2008).

Please search on SO before posting question.