# Search records with code pattern in column value c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities

I have one code of employee which is `A-B-C-D-` . Now I want to search all records which are starting with A- till it rich A-B-C-D-. I have tried below code:

```
var result = db.Employee.Where(x=> x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith("A-B-C-D-"));
```

Above code gives me only one record. But I want all records which starts with `A-` then `A-B-` then `A-B-C-` and then equals to `A-B-C-D-`.

Any hint or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
var result = db.Employee
   .Where(x=> x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith("A-")
              || x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith("A-B-")
              || x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith("A-B-C-")
              || x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith("A-B-C-D-");
```

As you say in the comment that it must be dynamic, then do something like this:

```
string code = "A-B-C-D-";
var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Customer,bool>>>();
for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
{
    if (code[i] == '-')
    {
        var prefix = code.Substring(0, i + 1);
        predicates.Add(x => x.EmployeeCode.StartsWith(prefix));
    }
}
var oredPredicates = ...; // Keep reading!

...

var result = db.Employee.Where(oredPredicate);
```

Now, you have a lis of predicates, and have to combine them with `||` (or). To do so it's a bit messy, but there are solutions, for example like in this SO Q&A's:

- [Combining two expressions (Expression>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool)
- [Combine two Linq lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433316/combine-two-linq-lambda-expressions)
- [How can I combine two lambda expressions without using Invoke method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613514/how-can-i-combine-two-lambda-expressions-without-using-invoke-method)
- [C# how to combine two expressions into a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840981/c-sharp-how-to-combine-two-expressions-into-a-new-one)

Once you have all the predicates combined, use it as parameter for your `.Where()` function.

Unfortunately the most complicated part of combining the expressions is unavoidable, and it's the toughest part to solve this problem, but it works. Please, read the 3 Q&A's, to get insight in what you're doing and get the code that best suits you (beware that using the simple `Expression.OrAlso` would not directly work, because the `x` param in each lambda is different for each created expression)

Comment: Will never work. Operator cannot applied to type string and string.

Comment: You're right. I've change my answer. I didn't have EF code at hand to test it. If you need to do something  like the previous version of my answer, use this: `.Where(x => x.EmployeeCode.CompareTo("A-B-C-D-") < 0)`. Is this what you're looking for or you code can greatly change between invocations?

Comment: If it's dynamic, it's harder to implement. I've explained the easiest part of the problem and gave you a reference to the toughest part. I use an extension method for comining predicates, but I don't have the code with me right now. See the other Q&A's. They exaplin and solve this quite complex problem