# Combining Func<bool> expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining two expressions (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool)

I have a method taking in a single `Expression<Func<bool>>` parameter

```
void MethodOne(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)
```

I've got multiple instances of `Expression<Func<bool>>`. How do I dynamically combine these expressions into a single `Expression<Func<bool>>` using `Expression.OrElse` (i.e. building up an expression tree)?

For example if I have two expressions such as

```
() => objectA.PropertyOneIsSet
```

and

```
() => objectB.PropertyTwoIsSet
```

I want the end result to be:

```
() => objectA.PropertyOneIsSet || objectB.PropertyTwoIsSet
```

so I can pass this to my method above.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool) which seems to include your problem...

Comment: something I forgot to mention: I have N of these expressions (more than 2) and I want to OrElse all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create ExpressionVisitor to combine queries. Check this msdn blog for more info: [Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) (Answer 3). He talking about EF, but you can use it in your case

Answer (score 3):

You could use expressions.Any(x => x.CallMethod) in order to achieve this goal.

Comment: I need to combine expressions selectively i.e. I don't want to always include all of the expressions in the end result. something like `if(someCondition) { result = result.OrElse(expressionN); }`

Comment: You need to prepare this collection of expressions dynamically, based on some business rule / logic. But to execute the aggregated collection using the Any extension method.

Comment: I need the result to be an instance of Func<Expression<bool>>. Any() will return just a bool.

Comment: Then you need something like that:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx