# LINQ Expression AndAlso with Nullable type

Tags: c#, linq

I am generating one `where` condition using a LINQ expression.

My entity is as follows;

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AnotherId { get; set; }
    public int? RelationId { get; set; }
}
```

I have to filter data based on 2 keys, namely `AnotherId` and `RelationId.RelationId` (optional). So in my method parameter `relationId` may not update and be 0.

Based on this I need to generate an expression:

```
Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> condition = x => x.AnotherId == anotherId;
if (relationId > 0)
{
    Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> additionalCondition = x => x.RelationId == relationId;
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Sample, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(condition, additionalCondition), condition.Parameters);
}
```

Here I got the following Exception in the `AndAlso` statement:

> The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Func``2[Sample,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[Sample,System.Boolean]'.

Please help me to correct my issue.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13968172/1559611) link

Comment: I think `condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Sample, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(condition.Body, additionalCondition.Body), condition.Parameters);` should work

Comment: Is it just `x.AnotherId == anotherId && (!relationId>0 || x.RelationId==relationId)`?

Comment: @kienct89 I checked and added that extension method but filter is not working.

Comment: @RobertMcKee it worked nice. a small change  x.AnotherId == anotherId && (!(relationId>0) || x.RelationId==relationId). But why this expression method not workint?

Comment: @Akhil you need to define the parameters and property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
if(!(relationId>0))
{ 
  Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> condition = x => x.AnotherId == anotherId;
} else {
  Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> condition = x => x.AnotherId == anotherId && x.RelationId == relationId;
}
```

or...

```
Expression<Func<Sample, bool>> condition = (!(relationId>0))
  ? x => x.AnotherId == anotherId
  : x => x.AnotherId == anotherId && x.RelationId == relationId;
```

Although most times when I see someone asking how to do this, it is because they are really trying to do this:

```
var query = something.Where(x=>x.AnotherId == anotherId);
if (relationId>0)
{
  query = query.Where(x=>x.RelationId == relationId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others might have pointed out, the simplest way is

```
x => x.AnotherId == anotherId && (relationId <= 0 || x.RelationId == relationId);
```

But if you still want to use `Expression`, maybe for future proof, you need to define the `parameter` and the `property`

Also, you need to convert your `anotherId` to `Nullable int`

Example:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Sample), "x");
var anotherIdParam = Expression.Property(param, "anotherId");
var condition = Expression.Equal(anotherIdParam, Expression.Constant(anotherId));

if (relationId > 0)
{
    var relationIdParam = Expression.Property(param, "relationId");
    var additionalCondition = Expression.Equal(relationIdParam, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(relationId), typeof(Nullable<int>)));
    condition = Expression.AndAlso(condition, additionalCondition);
}

var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Sample, bool>>(condition, param);
```