# Concatenate Expression<Action<T>>

Tags: action, expression, concatenation

I [saw an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool) that shows how I can Concatenate two `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` variables.

But is here some ways to do this also with `Expression<Action<T>>` ?

Here is what I have tried:

```
public static Expression<Action<T>> Add<T>(this Expression<Action<T>> left, Expression<Action<T>> right)
{
    //var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var body = Expression.AndAssign(
            Expression.Invoke(left),
            Expression.Invoke(right)
        );
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(body);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that this is .NET and C#, but I shouldn't have to. Please add appropriate language tag(s) (If for no other reason, so that the syntax highlighting can kick in)