# Convert Expression<Func<T1,bool>> to Expression<Func<T2,bool> dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I cannot find the way to convert from Expression<Func<T1,bool>> to Expression<Func<T2,bool>>. Since Im using a lot of reflection, in fact, what I really need is a method which takes a type parameter and performs the conversion.

```
public object Convert(Expression<Func<T1,bool>> expr, Type t);
```

T2 is derived from T1

```
public class T1 {
     int FamilyId {get; set;}
}

public class T2 : T1 {
     ... other properties
}
```

I am defining a filter expression on the base class

```
Expression<Func<T1,bool>> filter = p => p.FamilyId == [some value]
```

that i want to apply to a List<T2>

Comment: `what I really need is a method which takes a type parameter and performs the conversion.` - What? what is the `bool` for? do you need a conversion method? or a conditional one? I don't understand

Comment: How are `T1` and `T2` related?  Is there even a way to convert between them?

Comment: T2 is derived from T1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? There are two flavors of the method: the first lets you pass in the new input type as an argument; the second lets you pass in the input type as a generic parameter and get a strongly typed LambdaExpression.

```
    public static LambdaExpression ChangeInputType<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression, Type newInputType)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(newInputType))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} is not assignable from {1}.", typeof(T), newInputType));
        var beforeParameter = expression.Parameters.Single();
        var afterParameter = Expression.Parameter(newInputType, beforeParameter.Name);
        var visitor = new SubstitutionExpressionVisitor(beforeParameter, afterParameter);
        return Expression.Lambda(visitor.Visit(expression.Body), afterParameter);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T2, TResult>> ChangeInputType<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> expression)
    {
        if (!typeof(T1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T2)))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} is not assignable from {1}.", typeof(T1), typeof(T2)));
        var beforeParameter = expression.Parameters.Single();
        var afterParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), beforeParameter.Name);
        var visitor = new SubstitutionExpressionVisitor(beforeParameter, afterParameter);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, TResult>>(visitor.Visit(expression.Body), afterParameter);
    }

    public class SubstitutionExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Expression before, after;
        public SubstitutionExpressionVisitor(Expression before, Expression after)
        {
            this.before = before;
            this.after = after;
        }
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == before ? after : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible make the similar expression when T2 doesn't inherits from T1?

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for is very unwise. How would the compiler ever know if T1 is can be converted to T2? Seems like asking for awful run-time errors even if it is possible.*

(*I don't think its possible since you are trying to combine refection with nested generic types.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to combine 2 expressions - `T2` to `T1` conversion and than call to `expr` with given result.

This question discusses [Combining two expressions (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool) in general. For your case I think you need [Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323927.aspx) to construct conversion expression and than again to call original expression with result of conversion.