# Convert Expression<Func<IBar, T>> to Expression<Func<Bar, T>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do you convert from `Expression<Func<IBar, T>>` to `Expression<Func<Bar, T>>` when Bar implements IBar?

There is the answer to this more generic question:

[Convert Expression<Func<T1,bool>> to Expression<Func<T2,bool> dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212779/convert-expressionfunct1-bool-to-expressionfunct2-bool-dynamically)

Is that the best method in this case?  Is there not an easier way given that Bar implements IBar?

So, given this contrived example code:

```
          public class Foo<T>
          {
                 private readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();

                 public void Add(T item)
                 {
                       _list.Add(item);
                 }

                 public bool AnyFunc(Func<T, bool> predicate)
                 {
                       return _list.Any(predicate);
                 }

                 public bool AnyExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
                 {
                       return _list.AsQueryable().Any(expression);
                 }                    
          }

          public interface IBar
          {
                 string Name { get; }
          }

          public class Bar : IBar
          {
                 public string Name { get; set; }
          }
```

This demonstrates the problem:

```
          public class Test()
          {
                 private Foo<Bar> _foobar = new Foo<Bar>(); 

                 public void SomeMethodFunc(Func<IBar, bool> predicate)
                 {
                       // WILL COMPILE AND WORKS, casts from Func<IBar, bool> to Func<Bar, bool>
                       var found = _foobar.AnyFunc(predicate);
                 }

                 public void SomeMethodExpression(Expression<Func<IBar, bool>> expression)
                 {
                       // WON'T COMPILE - Can't cast from Expression<Func<IBar, bool>> to Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>  
                       var found = _foobar.AnyExpression(expression);
                 }
          }
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish something similar to SomeMethodExpression?

Comment: Have you looked at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)? Depending on your use case it's [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace may solve your issue. But can't say for sure without seeing how you are using `Func<Foo, T>` in a non-contrived example.

Comment: I don't get the question. Judging by your code it seems you're saying "I do this, and it works. I do this other thing, and it doesn't.". If one method works, why are you concerned about the other?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: the one that works uses delegates, the other uses expression trees.

Comment: You didn't understand my comment/question. You're saying this: a works, b doesn't. Why can't you use a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this case is simple and related to "casting" issues only, there is a shortcut:

```
public void SomeMethodExpression(Expression<Func<IBar, bool>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(expression.Body, expression.Parameters);
    var found = _foobar.AnyExpression(lambda);
}
```