# How to union two lambda Expression<Func>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have two entities (`ChildA` and `ChildB`) inheriting from the same entity (`Parent`). So two expression each from child entities are as follows:

`Expression<Func<T, Parent>> aExpression =
                        t=> t.ChildAs.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();`

Expression<Func<T, Parent>> bExpression =
                        t => t.ChildBs.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

`CreatedDate` is a field in `Parent` entity. I want to union these two expressions and put conditions on the final expression. How to union these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool?rq=1

Comment: Could you post Parent and ChildA/B classes ?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "union-ing" of expressions ? Do you want a resulting expression which holds some laws ? Is the "union-ing" of the two expressions still in the form of `Expression<Func<T, Parent>>` ?

Comment: @EduardDumitru: Yes, Actually in the child tables records are saved with same IDs in the parent. But for same t there exists records in ChildA and ChildB. But there is no reference for t in Parent table. I want to take latest record of Parent for t. Hence trying to union the latest record from both the tables and getting the latest out of them.

Comment: It is not clear where and when you use these expressions in your code. We have no leverage.

Answer (score 0):

As my requirement was to get the latest Parent of t, I could not find a way to do it through union. But I could do it this way,

`Expression<Func<T, Parent>> latestParentExpression = t => (aExpression.Invoke(t).CreatedDate >= bExpression.Invoke(t).CreatedDate)?aExpression.Invoke(t):bExpression.Invoke(t);`