# Sum of two expressions that return a number

Tags: c#, linq, expression, iqueryable

I have a list and a query simply defined as this:

```
var list = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

var query = list.AsQueryable();
```

Now I have an `Expression` which returns the square of the number:

```
private static Expression<Func<int, int>> Square()
{
    return i => i * i;
}
```

and the third power like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<int, int>> Third()
{
    return i => i * i * i;
}
```

What I want is to be able to select the sum of these in the `Select` expression with a code similar to this pseudocode:

```
var result = query.Select(Square() + Third()).ToList();
```

I expect the result to be

```
0
2
12
36
```

Is there a way to easily achieve that or I should do it some other way?

P.S. keep in mind, the methods are simplified to stress for ease of defining the issue.

P.S. I am using expressions because this is oversimplified example of the Linq-to-entities issue and I understood that I can only use `IQueryable` as of [this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx).

Comment: That should be called `Cube()`, not `Third()`.

Comment: Apparently I forgot to include that I will use this for linq to entities ;( According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx I have to use expressions. At the moment I am feeling stupid for oversimplifying the issue. Or maybe I am wrong and you can manage to complete the task without Expressions?

Comment: If you want to make it an entity query, you do need expressions, and that changes the way the answer can work.

Comment: I think the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool covers combining (also it shows specific bool case). If not - search for other "[C#] expression combine" questions first and comment why this is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need expression trees, use [`Expression.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354402.aspx) static method on `Square().Body` and `Third().Body`.

If you just need delegates, use `x => Square().Compile()(x) + Third().Compile()(x)`.

Comment: You'll also need to rewrite parameters.

Comment: @SLaks I agree, some details are missing from my answer. He needs to build up a whole new expression tree from scratch, but the `Expression.Add` is the fundamental ingredient.

Comment: With the help of `SwapVisitor` I managed to do it. Yay! Thank you very much :)