# Aggregate two expressions in c# syntax

Tags: c#

How to aggregate two expressions in C#?
For example:

```
public virtual List<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filters, bool includeHistory = false, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
{
    // HOW TO DO THIS?
    filters = includeHistory ? filters : filters.Add(e=>e.DeleteDate == null);    
    List<T> entities = _baseDao.List<T>(filters, sorting, include)                   
}
```

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: What guarantees that T will have DeleteDate?

Comment: This is part of method of Generic class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool?rq=1)

Very good extension method to Expression class

Answer (score 0):

Joe Albahari (Author of C# 3.0 in a Nutshell and LINQPad) wrote a utility called PredicateBuilder which can be used to AND and OR functions together.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

While it works on functions it is open source so you can check it out and see how it works.