# Expression parameter is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I am trying to perform a query against a list to give immediate results using an expression that is set elsewhere in the code, while a second thread goes off and uses it to get a full set of results from a database in a Linq query.

I know that the expression itself is OK as when I send it over the wire to the server side and apply it against an `IQueryable` then it will work. However, when applied on the client side the following error is produced:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable 'item' of type 'MissionControlSuite.Shared.Interface.Model.IBox' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

This code that performs the filtering:

```
public abstract class GridWithPaging<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> _items

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<IGridFilter<T>> Filters { get; set; }

    // more code skipped for breveity

    public void FiltersChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> combined = item => true;
        foreach (var filter in Filters)
            combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(filter.Expression.Body, combined.Body),
                combined.Parameters.Single());

        Filter = combined;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter");
    }

    public void AddFilter(IGridFilter<T> filter)
    {
        Filters.Add(filter);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Filters");
    }

    private void DoFiltering(int start)
    {
        var newView = _items.Skip(start);
        if(Filter != null)
            newView = newView.AsQueryable().Where(Filter);

        //some more code that acts on the filtered list
    }
}
```

The expression is set elsewhere like this:

```
Expression<Func<IBox, bool>> expression = item => item.BoxId.Contains(v);

var filter = new GridFilter<IBox>()
{
    Name = string.Format("{0} contains {1}", Property, Value),
    Expression = expression
};

Grid.AddFilter(filter);
```

Comment: The method FiltersChanged needs to get the data from the sender parameter and not from the Filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will help you: [Combining two expressions (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool)

To summarize: The problem is that the parameters, although with the same name, are not the same **instance** of the `ParameterExpression` - which is included in the [comment to that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool?rq=1#comment83854568_457328).

The solution is to use a Visitor (code copied over from linked post):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(
    this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));

    var leftVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr1.Parameters[0], parameter);
    var left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);

    var rightVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], parameter);
    var right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(left, right), parameter);
}



private class ReplaceExpressionVisitor
    : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldValue;
    private readonly Expression _newValue;

    public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
    {
        _oldValue = oldValue;
        _newValue = newValue;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldValue)
            return _newValue;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Also note: the ORM provider (or another IQueryable you use) probably works because it translates that to text directly, whereas executing (`Invoke`ing) this `LambdaExpression` causes the error as it's more strict, in a way. Some `IQueryable`s can also accept simple `string` parameters and parse that on their own, which should indicate that they have a wider range of acceptable inputs.