# .net core - combine a list of func with or to a single func

Tags: linq, generics, asp.net-core, .net-core, func

Hello i try to generate a single Func from a list combined by or.

```
var funcs = new List<Func<User, bool>>()
{
    (u) => u.Id.Equals(entityToFind.Id),
    (u) => u.UserName == entityToFind.UserName,
    (u) => u.Email == entityToFind.Email
};

//TODO: Some magic that funs is euqaly to that:

Func<User, bool> func =  (u) => u.Id.Equals(entityToFind.Id) || u.UserName == entityToFind.UserName || u.Email == entityToFind.Email;
```

I also tried it with Expressions, like that:

```
private Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, bool>>>     private Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, bool>>> test(User entityToFind)
{
    return new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, bool>>>() {
        {"Id", (u) => u.Id.Equals(entityToFind.Id) },
        {"Name", (u) => u.UserName == entityToFind.UserName },
        {"Email", (u) => u.Email == entityToFind.Email }
    };
}


public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToOrExpression<T>(this Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> dict)
{
    var expressions = dict.Values.ToList();
    if (!expressions.Any())
    {
        return t => true;
    }

    var delegateType = typeof(Func<T, bool>)
        .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        .MakeGenericType(new[]
            {
                typeof(T),
                typeof(bool)
            }
        );

    var tfd = Expression.OrElse(expressions[0], expressions[1]);

    var combined = expressions
        .Cast<Expression>()
        .Aggregate( (e1, e2) => Expression.OrElse(e1, e2) );

    return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(delegateType, combined);
}


test(entityToFind).ToOrExpression();
```

But there i will get the following error:

The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[Models.User,System.Boolean]' and 
 'System.Func`2[Models.User,System.Boolean]'

Comment: Is this for Entity Framework by any chance?

Comment: @DavidG yes and for a MongoClient

Comment: So you're already on a bad premise by using `Func` and not `Expression`

Comment: I will use:  return u => generatedFunc(entityToFind); at the end ;)

Comment: @DavidG but if you know a solution using Expressions i will be fine also with that

Comment: @DavidG i extend my question by my tries with Expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you could create a wrapper method to combine a bunch of `Func`s, because you are using Entity Framework, that would cause the entire dataset to be downloaded into memory and the search done locally. What you should be using is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead.

Fortunately [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) has [already written a handy bit of code to combine expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/1663001). Your question is strictly a dupliucate because you want to combine more than 2 together, but that is quite easy with a little Linq. So, lets start with your expressions first, the code barely changes:

```
var expressions = new List<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>()
{
    (u) => u.Id.Equals(entityToFind.Id),
    (u) => u.UserName == entityToFind.UserName,
    (u) => u.Email == entityToFind.Email
};
```

Now using Marc's code and modifying it to be `or` instead of `and`:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var leftVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr1.Parameters[0], parameter);
        var left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);

        var rightVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], parameter);
        var right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(left, right), parameter);
    }

    private class ReplaceExpressionVisitor
    : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Expression _oldValue;
        private readonly Expression _newValue;

        public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
        {
            _oldValue = oldValue;
            _newValue = newValue;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            if (node == _oldValue)
                return _newValue;
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

No you combine your expressions with the Linq `Aggregate` method:

```
var combinedExpression = expressions.Aggregate((x, y) => x.OrElse(y));
```

And use it something like this:

```
var result = db.Things.Where(combinedExpression);
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! That is working, now i only try to get how this is working... ;)