# Allow the use of class function in where-expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Are there any way to get the following expression to work in EF Core 3.1?

```
_db.Customers
   .Where(customer => customer.IsFavorite(userId))
   .ToList();
```

IsFavorite is a simple expression that compares multiple properties with the userId. This could obviously be rewritten as

```
_db.Customers
   .Where(customer => customer.Prop1 == userId || customer.Prop2 == userId)
   .ToList();
```

But i'd like to avoid duplicating this logic. Other uses are when filtering on child properties, such as:

```
_db.Orders
   .Where(order => order.Customer.IsFavorite(userId))
   .ToList();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you ask, how to combine multiple expressions into  one ? Here are several approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool

Comment: If `Customer` is defined as a class you could just use an extension method.

Comment: What's the problem you're running into? AFAIK you can use class methods in LINQ expressions, the problem however is that the data provider cannot translate it into SQL

Comment: @MindSwipe That is the problem yes. Any ways to make it translateable?

Comment: Making a method that returns the expression could maybe help, I'd need to check though. If it works it would solve the problem of the entirety being loaded while allowing you to reuse the code

Comment: That is the goal yes. Would be much appreciated, although I would prefer if the method could return bool instead of an expression.

Comment: Your other option would be to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) which provides support for inline expansion of methods so that they can be later translated to SQL. `Customer.IsFavorite` would still need to return a `LambdaExpression`.