# Want to convert c# multiple Linq into one Linq query?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, output-window

I wrote the code with multiple if conditions and get list of Ids from each if statement. I want to write that whole code into one linq query if possible then let me know.

The issue is when we are running this code then can see our compiler runs hundreds line of query on output window. I just want to optimized. If you guys can help me. 
Following code for details:

```
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._0to5))
{
    var list = queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= yearNow && v.BuildYear > year5).Select(s => s.Id);
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._6to10))
{
    var list = queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year5 && v.BuildYear > year10).Select(s => s.Id);
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._11to15))
{
    var list = queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year10 && v.BuildYear > year15).Select(s => s.Id);
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._16to20))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year15 && v.BuildYear > year20).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._21to25))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year20 && v.BuildYear > year25).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._26to30))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year25 && v.BuildYear > year30).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._31to35))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year30 && v.BuildYear > year35).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._36to40))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year35 && v.BuildYear > year40).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._Over41Years))
{
    var list = Ids.Concat(queryRecord.Where(v => v.BuildYear <= year40).Select(s => s.Id));
    Ids = Ids.Concat(list);
}
queryRecord = queryRecord.Where(v => Ids.Contains(v.Id));
```

I tested with following code but because of same column It fulfill first condition.

```
                    Ids = queryRecord.Where(st => ((queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._11to15)) ? st.BuildYear <= year10 && st.BuildYear > year15 : true) &&
                        ((queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._6to10)) ? st.BuildYear <= year5 && st.BuildYear > year10 : true))
                        .Select(s => s.Id);
```

Comment: How about replacing the `if` statements with `if..else if...`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool

Comment: @UweKeim No actually I can't because It might be possible both conditions will be fulfill and want other condition record as well.

Comment: @canton7 This reference you have mentioned above doesn't relate to mine.

Comment: Is that real code? Every condition results in the same operation: collect IDs. Just reduce the code to a single select query.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanAli Well it lays down the foundation for what you need to do, which is to combine all of your AND expression using ORs

Comment: @BionicCode I can't reduce the code to a single one. I don't have similar check in every condition. Could you please do for me.

Comment: This might benefit from a custom SQL query.  Do a Google search for "executing raw queries in entity framework."

Comment: Though I'm inclined to agree with bionic.  This is most likely a single select.

Comment: I added an answer. But I am confused why age category '21 to 25' returns every buildYear <= 20 && > 25 and not > 20 && < 26?

Comment: Is this an exclude filter, like every age except those of a certain range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added false in each case and add || between each statements and fixed this.

```
Ids = queryRecord.Where(st => 
                    ((queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._11to15)) ? st.BuildYear <= year10 && st.BuildYear > year15 : false) ||
                    ((queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._6to10)) ? st.BuildYear <= year5 && st.BuildYear > year10 : false)
                    ).Select(s => s.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with Marc's `AndAlso` method from [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/1086121), and change `AndAlso` to `OrElse`:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(
    this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    var leftVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr1.Parameters[0], parameter);
    var left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);

    var rightVisitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], parameter);
    var right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.OrElse(left, right), parameter);
}

private class ReplaceExpressionVisitor
    : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldValue;
    private readonly Expression _newValue;

    public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
    {
        _oldValue = oldValue;
        _newValue = newValue;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldValue)
            return _newValue;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

That lets us write:

```
Expression<Func<Whatever, bool>> query = t => false;

if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._0to5))
{
    query = query.OrElse(v => v.BuildYear <= yearNow && v.BuildYear > year5);
}
if (queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains((int)AgeList._6to10))
{
    query = query.OrElse(v => v.BuildYear <= year5 && v.BuildYear > year10);
}
... and so on...

queryRecord = whatever.Where(query);
```

This generates a single query, which will look like:

```
WHERE (BuildYear <= yearNow AND BuildYear > year5) OR (BuildYear < year5 AND BuildYear > year10) etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `AgeList` you are referring to was an enum like this:

```
public enum AgeList
{
    _0to5   = 0,
    _6to10  = 1,
    _11to15 = 2,
    _16to20 = 3,
    _21to25 = 4,
    _26to30 = 5,
    _31to35 = 6,
    _36to40 = 7,
}
```

I think you want to map the `BuildYear`s to one of the above, and we can observe they go in fives.
So we could do:

```
var yearNow = 2020;
var buildYear = 2019;

var ageGroupNumber = (yearNow - buildYear) / 5; // 0
var ageGroup = (AgeList) ageGroupNumber;        // _0to5
```

So could we then do something like the following?

```
Ids = queryObj.AgeCategory
    .SelectMany(category => // For every category :
        queryRecord.Where(v => // Select the items in this category :
            (DateTime.Now.Year - v.BuildYear) / 5 == (int) category 
        )
        .Select(s => s.Id)
    );
```

I don't know if this will help you, or if I understood your problem correctly, but maybe this will 
give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a converter that transforms the `BuildAge` into an age category. This way you can simply let LINQ do the filtering:

```
private void FilterQueryRecord(IEnumerable<Record> queryRecord, ? queryObj)
{
  this.Ids = queryRecord
    .Where(item => queryObj.AgeCategory.Contains(ConvertBuildYearToAgeCategory(item.BuildYear)))
    .Select(item => item.Id)
    .ToList();
}

private int ConvertBuildYearToAgeCategory(int buildYear) 
{
  switch (buildYear)
  {
    case int value when value <= yearNow && value > year5: return (int) AgeList._0to5;
    case int value when value <= year5 && value > year10: return (int) AgeList._6to10;
    case int value when value <= year10 && value > year15: return (int) AgeList._11to15;
    case int value when value <= year15 && value > year20: return (int) AgeList._16to20;
    case int value when value <= year20 && value > year25: return (int) AgeList._21to25;
    case int value when value <= year25 && value > year30: return (int) AgeList._26to30;
    case int value when value <= year30 && value > year35: return (int) AgeList._31to35;
    case int value when value <= year35 && value > year40: return (int) AgeList._36to40;
    case int value when value < year40: return (int) AgeList._Over41Years;
    default: return (int) AgeList.Undefined
  }
}
```