# How can I create a Linq AND expression in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have been trying to create an AND expression in Linq with no satisfactory results. This is the method I have created:

```
private List<Item> GetItems(int projectId, bool checkFlag)
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> sqlExpression = item => item.ProjectId == projectId;

    if (checkFlag)
    {
        Expression<Func<Item, bool>> newExpression = item => item.Flag;
        sqlExpression = Expression.And(sqlExpression, newExpression);
    }

    return db.Table<Items>().Where(sqlExpression).ToList();
}
```

And this is the Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```

The problem at compile time is located at the line where the AND expression is created:

```
Expression.And(sqlExpression, newExpression);
```

The error that Visual Studio returns is:

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression' to
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Item, bool>>' (CS0029)

I know this example could be fixed just by changing the first expression, but it is not what I intended to do:

```
Expression<Func<Item, bool>> sqlExpression = item => (item.ProjectId == projectId) && (!checkFlag || item.Flag);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to solve this by constructing a new expression that combines them both? Normally I would just do `var result = db.Table<Items>().Where(i => i.ProjectId == projectId);` then `if (checkFlag) result = result.Where(i => i.Flag);` finally `return result.ToList();`

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here. The first is that if you use `Expression.And`, this is equivalent to the binary operator `&`, which is probably not what you want. You have to write

```
Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2)
```

to get the equivalent of `e1 && e2`.

The bigger problem is that you are trying to combine two lambda expressions with `&&`, which is not possible because `&&` works on boolean expressions. What you want is, given two lambda expressions `lambda1 = x => e1` and `lambda2 = x => e2`, return `x => e1 && e2`.

In order to achieve this, follow these steps:

1. Create a new `ParameterExpression` `p`.
2. Replace the parameter in `lambda1.Body` by `p` (you can do this with an `ExpressionVisitor`) to get `renamedBody1`.
3. Replace the parameter in `lambda2.Body` by `p` to get `renamedBody2`.
4. Now you can construct

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
    Expression.AndAlso(renamedBody1, renamedBody2), p);
```

This is the expression you can use as argument of the `Where` method.

---

**Note:** you can avoid the parameter renaming if you make sure that you use the same parameter expression while constructing the two lambda expressions, using `Expression.Lambda()`. But then you can't construct them as elegantly using the `=>` syntax as you did in your code, which produces *different* parameters even though they are named `item` in both lambda expressions.

---

## The full code

Alternatively, just use the `And` extension method in the following code (`lambda1.And(lambda2)`):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods related to <see cref="Expression" />.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ExpressionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Renames all parameter names equal to <paramref name="oldParameterName" /> in
        /// <paramref name="expression" /> to <paramref name="newParameter" />.
        /// </summary>
        [NotNull]
        public static Expression ReplaceParameter([NotNull] this Expression expression,
            [NotNull] string oldParameterName,
            [NotNull] ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
            if (oldParameterName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldParameterName));
            if (newParameter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newParameter));
            AlphaRenamingExpressionVisitor visitor =
                new AlphaRenamingExpressionVisitor(oldParameterName, newParameter);
            return visitor.Visit(expression).AsNotNull();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the conjunction of the two given predicate expressions, performing alpha renamings if necessary.
        /// </summary>
        [NotNull]
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>([NotNull] this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1,
            [NotNull] Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2)
        {
            if (e1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(e1));
            if (e2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(e2));
            return binaryOperation(e1, e2, Expression.AndAlso);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the negation of the given predicate expression.
        /// </summary>
        [NotNull]
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>([NotNull] this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1)
        {
            if (e1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(e1));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(e1.Body),
                e1.Parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the disjunction of the two given predicate expressions, performing alpha renamings if necessary.
        /// </summary>
        [NotNull]
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>([NotNull] this Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1,
            [NotNull] Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2)
        {
            if (e1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(e1));
            if (e2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(e2));
            return binaryOperation(e1, e2, Expression.OrElse);
        }

        [NotNull]
        private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> binaryOperation<T>([NotNull] Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1,
            [NotNull] Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2, [NotNull] Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> binaryOp)
        {
            if (binaryOp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(binaryOp));
            if (e1.Parameters[0].Equals(e2.Parameters[0]))
            {
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryOp(e1.Body, e2.Body), e1.Parameters[0]);
            }

            ParameterExpression newParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

            Expression renamedBody1 = e1.Body.ReplaceParameter(e1.Parameters[0].Name, newParam);
            Expression renamedBody2 = e2.Body.ReplaceParameter(e2.Parameters[0].Name, newParam);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryOp(renamedBody1, renamedBody2),
                newParam);
        }

        private class AlphaRenamingExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            [NotNull] private readonly string oldParameterName;
            [NotNull] private readonly ParameterExpression newParameter;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="AlphaRenamingExpressionVisitor" /> with the given parameters.
            /// </summary>
            public AlphaRenamingExpressionVisitor([NotNull] string oldParameterName,
                [NotNull] ParameterExpression newParameter)
            {
                this.oldParameterName = oldParameterName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldParameterName));
                this.newParameter = newParameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newParameter));
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            [NotNull]
            protected override Expression VisitParameter([NotNull] ParameterExpression node)
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
                }

                return node.Name == oldParameterName ? newParameter : node;
            }
        }
    }
```