# How to combine expressions Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> to a single Expression<Func<T2, bool>>

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

I have a list of conditions composed of two Funcs:

```
   public Func<TConfiguration, string> ConfigurationField { get;}
   public Func<TNumbering, string> NumberingField { get; }
```

For each condition, expression would look like this:

```
Expression<Func<TNumbering, TConfiguration, bool>>  (n, c) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n)
```

I need to chain the list of these expressions with OrElse.

I tried doing something like:

```
BinaryExpression expression = null;

        foreach (var criteria in SelectionCriteria)
        {
            Expression<Func<TNumbering, TConfiguration, bool>> exp = (n, c) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n);
            expression = expression == null ? exp : Expression.OrElse(expression, exp);
        }
        if (expression == null) return Result.Failure("Expression not defined"));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TConfiguration, bool>>(expression);
        numberingsToRemove = numberings.Where(_ => configurations.All(lambda));
```

However, compiler doesn't like it, says there is no implicit conversion between Expression.Lambda<Func<TConfiguration, bool>> and Binary expression.

If I use

```
 expression = expression == null ? Expression.OrElse(exp, exp) : Expression.OrElse(expression, exp);
```

I get

> The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Func<TNumbering,TConfiguration,System.Boolean> and 'System.Func<TNumbering,TConfiguration,System.Boolean>.

I am new to building expressions, can somebody point me in the right direction how to do this?

Comment: Maybe replace `exp` with `Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, exp, exp)` in ternary?

Comment: @Auditive - i tried something similar before as well, I have updated the question accordingly, but i then get the error: Binary operator OrElse is not defined for types of System.Func<TNumbering,TConfiguration,System.Boolean>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append expressions in linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822157/how-to-append-expressions-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Expression<Func<TNumbering, TConfiguration, bool>>` is a generic type whose open generic type is [**Expression<TDelegate>**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1), where **TDelegate** is some delegate type; in this case `Func<TNumbering, TConfiguration, bool>`.

**Expression<TDelegate>** inherits from [**LambdaExpression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression), which represents a C# (or VB.NET) [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Just like you couldn't write the following code:

```cs
var result = 
    (n, c) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n) ||
    (n1, c1) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c1) != criteria.NumberingField(n1);
```

trying to combine two **LambdaExpression**s with `OrElse` would throw an exception at runtime.

Your code isn't even compiling, because `expression` is typed as **BinaryExpression**, meaning an expression corresponding to this:

```cs
criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n) ||
criteria.ConfigurationField(c1) != criteria.NumberingField(n1)
```

into which you're trying to put a full **Expression<TDelegate>**, which includes (for example) the parameter list.

---

Every **LambdaExpression** has a **Body** property, which extracts from an expression corresponding to this:

```cs
(n, c) => criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n)
```

the body of the **LambdaExpression**, or an expression corresponding to this:

```cs
criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n)
```

which, in theory, you could then combine into a **BinaryExpression** corresponding to this:

```cs
criteria.ConfigurationField(c) != criteria.NumberingField(n) ||
criteria.ConfigurationField(c1) != criteria.NumberingField(n1)
```

But this wouldn't work either, because each iteration introduces multiple new parameters, all of which you'd have to pass in to the final lambda.

---

It's possible to work around this problem, but I would suggest first and foremost you map each element in `SelectionCriteria` to an expression corresponding to the criteria evaluation, using the factory methods at **System.Linq.Expressions.Expression**. You could then combine those expressions into a **BinaryExpression** which you could then wrap up in a **LambdaExpression** or even an **Expression**.

It might look something like this (making some assumptions):

```cs
class Criteria<TConfiguration, TNumbering> {
    public Func<TConfiguration, string> ConfigurationField { get;}
    public Func<TNumbering, string> NumberingField { get; }
}

// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

var SelectionCritera = new List<Criteria>();

/*
 * populate list here
 */

var configParam = Parameter(typeof(TConfiguration));
var numberingParam = Parameter(typeof(TNumbering));
var expressions =
    SelectionCriteria.Select(criteria => {
        var criteriaExpr = Constant(criteria);

        return NotEqual(                   // !=
            Invoke(                        // ( ... )
                PropertyOrField(           // .ConfigurationField
                    criteriaExpr,          // criteria
                    "ConfigurationField"
                ),
                configParam                // c
            ),
            Invoke(                        // ( ... )
                PropertyOrField(           // .NumberingField
                    criteriaExpr,          // criteria
                    "NumberingField"
                ),
                numberingParam             // n
            )
        );  
    })
    .ToList();

if (!expressions.Any) { return Result.Failure("Expression not defined")); }

// Combine all the subexpressions using ||
var body = expressions.Aggregate((prev, next) => OrElse(prev, next));

// Create a LambdaExpression
var lmbd = Lambda<Func<TConfiguration, TNumbering, bool>>(body, configParam, numberingParam);

// Create a .NET method from the LambdaExpression
var mthd = lmbd.Compile();

// Apply the method to each config/numbering pair
var result = (
    from config in configs
    from numbering in numbering
    select (config, numbering)
).All(x => mthd(config, numbering));
```