# Combine two properties to form an object with c# expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a class

```
class MyClass
{
  string Foo { get; set; }
  int Bar { get; set; }
  //... Other properties
}
```

Now what I have is two expressions

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> expr1 = x => x.Foo;
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> expr2 = x => x.Bar > 0;
```

Using this two expressions, I want to create an expression which is something like this

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr = x => new { Foo = x.Foo, Baz = x.Bar > 0 };
```

In other words I want to combine two properties into one anonymous object using expression trees.
My problem is,
How do I create a similar expression from the given two expressions?

I want to use final expression in a join statement with entity framework query.
The bool part is complex and need to generate dynamically.
If any alternative idea to this, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (If this is for Entity Framework then be aware that EF/EF-Core only supports a small subset of possible `Expression<>` types with `IQueryable`).

Comment: Yes, It is for entity framework. Actually x.Bar > 0 is very complex expression in real scenario. My idea is to construct an expression for a Join statement, because condition is complex

Comment: I don't think that will work at all, simply due to limitations inherent in EF.

Comment: This is easily done in C# but if it is for EF then the question has to say that.

Comment: I've edited question to mention entity framework

Comment: Do you know that JOIN can be expressed by `SelectMany`?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I got support from this answer
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool#answer-457328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool#answer-457328)