# merge expressions to use the same lambda parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

having an array of `Expression<Func<T, string>>` and a `string str`

which could have a value like this:
`{ m => m.FirstName, m => m.LastName}`

I wanted to generate a Lambda expression that does this:

`m => m.FirstName.Contains(str) || m.LastName.Contains(str)`

The problem is that when there's more than 1 Expression, each has its lambda parameter (`m =>`)

so when I call:

`Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(OrExpr,` here needs to be just one lambda parameter

(for now the only solution I know is to generate a new `Expression.Parameter` and new `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`[] using my new parameter)

Comment: "or now the only solution I know is to generate a new Expression.Parameter and new Expression.MakeMemberAccess[] using my new parameter" And wher's your problem with that? I'd expected to do exactly that.

Comment: that's what I would use if I had an array of strings as input `{ "FirstName", "LastName" }`, I thought that since I already have expressions maybe there's a more optimal way

Comment: more optimal regarding what? Expressions are easy and cheap to build, I'm not sure what kind of optimzation you're after here.

Comment: a more complex example `m => m.Prop1.Name`,  now I need to get `Prop.Name` as string and after do `typeof(TModel).GetProperty("Prop1")`,  `MakeMemberAccess` 2 times, and I thought all this ^ can be avoided because I already have an expression

Comment: You mean something like this: `Func<Person, bool> d = p => p.FirstName.Contains("a") || p.LastName.Contains("o");`

Comment: For further details, plase see [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)

Comment: Use `ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace` (or your own version) to replace the parameter in each property lambda body with the final parameter you want to use for the combined `Expression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `propFns` as an array of `Expression<Func<T, string>>` and `string str`, you can do:

```
var ansParam = propFns[0].Parameters[0];
var newBody = propFns.Select(f => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                                        ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(f.Parameters[0], ansParam, f.Body),
                                        typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(String) }),
                                        Expression.Constant(str))
              ).Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
var newLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestClass,bool>>(newBody, ansParam);
```

NOTE: If you are not using EF Core, and don't have `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` available, you can use your own version:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
/// </summary>
/// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
/// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
/// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
/// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
public static T Replace<T>(this T orig, Expression from, Expression to) where T : Expression => (T)new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);

/// <summary>
/// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    readonly Expression from;
    readonly Expression to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Comment: seems that this requires to install package EntityFramework.Core

Comment: @buga Yes, but you didn't say what LINQ you were using. You can replace `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` with your own class trivially - it is only a about ten lines of code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up using, copied the Visitor from Marc Gravell's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/11783857