# how to implement generic repository pattern and UoW in NHibernate 3.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, c#-4.0, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm new to `NHibernate` and I'm trying to impelement *Generic Repository Pattern* and *Unit of Work* for using in an *ASP.NET MVC 3* application. I googled the title and found new links; but all of them was more complexe to understanding by me. I use *StructureMap* as my *IOC*. Can you suggest me some links or blog posts please?

Comment: NHibernate's ISession already represents a unit of work and access to a repository.

Comment: A repository should encapsulate the data access layer, that is it will use but it will NOT expose Nhibernate. And a proper designed repository (for your needs, a generic repository is useless) should not need unit of work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of items to read thru:

- [Advantage of creating a generic repository vs. specific repository for each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230571/advantage-of-creating-a-generic-repository-vs-specific-repository-for-each-obje/1231473#1231473)
- [How to make a Generic Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527651/how-to-make-a-generic-repository)

The implementation I have used in my most recent project looked like:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetByID(int id);
    T GetByID(Guid key);
    void Save(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly ISession Session;

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Session.Query<T>();
    }

    public T GetByID(int id)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public T GetByID(Guid key)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(key);
    }

    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        Session.Save(entity);
        Session.Flush();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        Session.Delete(entity);
        Session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I got it. But now, how can I create an `ISession` object via injection? `public Repository(ISession session)` but it seems that the `ISession` can be created by `OpenSession` method only; for example, how to work with this repository via StructureMap? can more explain please?

Comment: @king.net I myself use ninject over structure map, however similar concepts would apply. Within ninject I would do something like this: Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()).InRequestScope();

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution - https://bitbucket.org/cedricy/cygnus/overview

Its a simple implementation of a Repository pattern that we've used in our production MVC 1, 2, and 3 applications.

Of course, we've learned since then that we really appreciate having our queries run directly against ISession.  You have more control over them that way.  That and [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer) told us not too.

Thanks Cedric!