# How should I use IoC DI with this repository pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, ioc-container, repository-pattern

I am using the repository pattern found in the answer to this SO question:

[Advantage of creating a generic repository vs. specific repository for each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230571/advantage-of-creating-a-generic-repository-vs-specific-repository-for-each-objec)

Namely, each repository inherits from an abstract base class that contains generic methods like add, delete, etc. and also implements a specific repository interface for any methods that are unique to that repository/entity.

ie.

```
public class CompanyRepository : Repository<Company>, ICompanyRepository {
...
}
```

In my business layer I am using Structure Map to get an instance of the repository, but I am unsure how to use it.

```
 // Structure Map initialisation
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(
 x =>
 {                    
      x.For<ICompanyRepository>().Use<CompanyRepository>();
 });
```

resolving an instance:

```
return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICompanyRepository>();
```

However the instance I get is an interface and not the whole repository implementation. I don't have access to the methods on the base class (`Repository<Company>`). What is the usual way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to think of `Repository<>` solely as an implementation detail. You won't be accessing any methods on it directly; instead, you will expose all methods, including `Insert` and `Delete`, on the interface:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    // ...Customer-specific queries...

    void Insert(Customer customer);

    void Delete(Customer customer);
}
```

When you implement the interface in `CustomerRepository`, you simply have to pass the `Insert` and `Delete` calls through to the protected methods of `Repository<>` as discussed in the original question.

The StructureMap registration you state in the question is exactly what I would expect. The purpose of `Repository<>` then is to aid in the implementation of entity-specific interfaces. Keep in mind that the interfaces will always contain the repository's full public API and that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Great -thanks for the clarification - I was missing the step of exposing the Repository<> methods on the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Repository<Company>>;
```

? You will have to modify accordingly your ObjectFactory initialization:

```
// Structure Map initialisation
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    x => {                    
      x.For<Repository<Company>>().Use<CompanyRepository>();
    });
```

**EDIT**
If you still want to get `Repository<Company>` also for `ICompanyRepository`, you need to declare a forwarding:

```
// Structure Map initialisation
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    x => {                    
      x.For<Repository<Company>>().Use<CompanyRepository>();
      x.Forward<Repository<Company>, ICompanyRepository>();
    });
```

Comment: Then I don't get access to the methods defined in the interface. I really need to get a CompanyRepository however I don't know if this will negate the benefit of DI/IoC?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How do I then get a CompanyRepository? return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Repository<Company>>() and cast it to a CompanyRepository? Seems to work.

Comment: You get it by `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Repository<Company>>` **or** by `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICompanyRepository>`.

Comment: It works but that's not what I'd do. You really should need the interface or the abstract base class, not the concrete class!

Comment: I guess that's the crux of my question - how can this particular repository pattern (with an abstract class and an interface)  properly use IoC? Perhaps it is a flaw in the pattern. Thanks for your time.