# How can I perform complex queries (eg. over many-to-many relationship) in Entity Framework using a repository pattern?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, repository, repository-pattern

I am using Entity Framework v4 and the repository pattern found in the answer to this SO question:

[Advantage of creating a generic repository vs. specific repository for each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230571/advantage-of-creating-a-generic-repository-vs-specific-repository-for-each-objec)

Namely, each repository inherits from an abstract base class that contains generic methods like add, delete, etc. and also implements a specific repository interface for any methods that are unique to that repository/entity.

ie.

```
public class CompanyRepository : Repository<Company>, ICompanyRepository {
     public Company Get(int id)
     {
       return base.ObjectSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
     }
}
```

How can I perform more complex queries that reference entities that are not part of this repository... (say across a many-to-many relationship to another table)?

```
public List<Company> GetAllCompaniesForUser(int userId) 
{
    return base.ObjectSet.Where(x => x.Users ?????
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be the way to do it:

```
return base.ObjectSet.Where(x => x.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId)).ToList();
```

or

```
var companies = from c in base.ObjectSet
                from u in c.Users
                where u.Id == userId
                select c;

return companies.ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. +1 for figuring it out yourself.