# ASP.Net MVC 3 - instantiate data context class in BaseController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

When adding a controller in ASP.Net MVC 3 using "Controller with Read/Write actions and views, using EntityFramework" as template, it generates a class as follows:

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{ 
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        private ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();

        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to know if it would be a good practice to change this so that my Controller would inherit a custom base controller that would instantiate ProjectEntities. It would look as follows:

BaseController:

```
namespace MatchesHorsConcours.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected MatchesEntities db = new MatchesEntities();
        ...
    }
}
```

Other controllers:

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{ 
    public class Default1Controller : BaseController
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better practice to use Dependency Injection. There are a number of libraries out there to do this. To name a few, Ninject, Castle Windsor or Autofac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No absolutely not. It makes totally untestable. Please use repository pattern and constructor injection if possible: [Repository Pattern vs DAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291344/repository-pattern-vs-dal)

Answer (score 2):

This technique is useful when you need logic in your master page (for example, to dynamically render menu options). Read about this here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs

However, in general this is not a good technique. I would recommend using dependency injection ([Ninject](http://ninject.org/) works well with MVC and is easy to implement)